# Single regex pattern for multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

Question is not duplicate with other SO questions because the answers are not matched with criteria listed, Please refer below.

Criteria to achieve with regex pattern for the input text is,

- Support at-least one Uppercase letter
- Support at-least one Lowercase letter
- Support at-least one Special character listed --> @ % $
- Support at-least one Digit

No Start and End Criteria.

Trying to achieve with below single regex,

```
^(
  (\w+\d+[@%\$]+)
     |
     (\d+[@%\$]+\w+)
        |
        ([@%\$]+\d+\w+)
             |
             (\w+[@%\$]+\d+)
)$
```

Problem is,

Support for at-least one uppercase is not working.
I am pretty sure that it is not a good approach to build the regex pattern.

Please help me to achieve these criteria in single regex pattern.

### Pass Criteria

Test@123
tesT@123
@123tesT
123@Test
TTTTeeeess@@@@$$$111112222
@@@@$$$1111TTT@@@$$esss

### Fail Criteria

Test (No special character) 
@123 
123 
@ 
T 
test 
test@123   (No Uppercase) 
Test@123&  ('&' not to be supported in the pattern) 
@123test  
@TTT123   (No Lowercase)

Comment: Why the requirement to use a single regex? You can do it using look-aheads, but at that point you're basically running multiple regexen anyway. If you broke it into four regexen, you could give each a meaningful name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use this single lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[$@%])[\w$@%]+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ1lL9/1)

Comment: @Nike: I used `\w` only because your attempts also used `\w` and `_` is not considered a special character, it is a word character.

Comment: You should changed all `*` to `*?`, it will be quicker.

Comment: Thanks @AMDcze: I did that but I think it depends on optimization of regex engine also.

Comment: I don't think optimalization will do anything here. Compare [lazy](https://regex101.com/r/tH2xX6/2) with [greedy](https://regex101.com/r/tH2xX6/1) in the regex debugger. Even if you disable the optimalization, the lazy one takes 34 and the greedy one 3679 steps.

Comment: @AMDcze: You may be right but I have read some regex specialists claiming here on SO that greedy regex behaves faster. I didn't get a chance to run any serious benchmark though.

Comment: In case you searched for it and found it, let me know. It'd be an interesting read for me.

Comment: After a little bit of reading and testing, the fastest regex would be this one: `^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^[$@%]*[$@%])[\w$@%]+$` The lazy one in my example makes hundreds of steps in case for example the only uppercase letter is at the end, so that wasn't the best solution.

Comment: Yes negation is definitely better than `.*` or `.*?`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (changed `\w` to `[a-zA-Z\d]` since you probably don't want `_` sign):

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[@%$])[a-zA-Z\d@%$]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kS3cI4/2

Comment: Thanks dude. I will accept the answer of anubhav since it matches with underscore(logically stronger except with my pass criteria).